# Read 16Bit Integer from 2 bytes big endian

Tags: java, integer, byte, endianness

I'm trying to following up this [tutorial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43743/how-to-extract-elevation-from-hgt-file) about reading altitude from srtm-data. At the end I have to read 2 bytes from a file, which are big-endian and have to convert them to an integer in java.

```
File file = new File(filename);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
long length = file.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

inputStream.read(bytes);
inputStream.close();

byte[] byteArr = new byte[2];
byteArr[0] = bytes[pos];
byteArr[1] = bytes[pos+1];

int height = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArr).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
```

The problem is I'm getting an

```
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
```

because java is expecting more bytes.
How can I convert these two bytes to an integer?

Comment: You could read a short and promote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer is comprised of 4 bytes, so your byteArr needs to have 4 elements, not 2:

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[4];
```

Comment: Thank you :) I have to set the first two bytes to 00x0 and the last two are the one from the file. Now it works :)